# Load different Storyboard for iPhone 5 @ app start

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I am using the following code in my **AppDelegate.m** to detect which device the user is using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 3,5 Inch");

            [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];



        }
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 4 Inch");
            [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5-storyboard" bundle:nil];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But when I build the App the NSLog is shown, but no Storyboard is coming up...

- The Main Storyboard field in the Deployment info is empty so that the code decided what to load...

Can you help me?

Comment: Any reason you need different storyboards, since you can switch between 3.5inch and 4inch layouts in the storyboard editor?

Comment: The Switch between the 3.5inch and the 4inch Layout is only a simulation, you are not be able to design different interfaces white this method!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a way I now found on a other post:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch


        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        UIViewController *initialViewController = nil;
        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
        {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
            UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone35" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        }

        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
        {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
            UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone4" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        }

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

    {   // The iOS device = iPad

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    }
```

Comment: I figured out... It was so obvious! hahahha

Comment: does that mean i need to emptied the entry list where it asks for storyboard file name?

Comment: Yes, remove them and than copy the code from above in to u AppDelegate.m where now to enter the names of the different storyboards...